# glPushMatrix() glPopMatrix() doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I try to code two object move independent which mean both are moving two different direction it's worked but it can't move continuous. when i put `glTranslatef()` at outside the `glPushMatrix()` ... `glPopMatrix()` it work normally.

```cpp
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.356, 0.701, 0.0, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // if put gltransate() at here the object will moving continuous

    glPushMatrix();
      glTranslatef(.5, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.8);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.8);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.5);
      glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
          glTranslatef(-.5, 0, 0);
      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(.0, .0, .0);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.2);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.2);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

}
```

i expect the for the first square objects will go to the right constantly but it seem like just translate once then stop at the position.

Comment: The you show needs to be put into the context of how/when you render to explain the problem. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @Yunnosch The issue is well explained. With the knowledge of OpenGL this example is verifiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, in general I recommend to use a math library like [OpenGL Mathematics](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) to do the matrix calculations and [`glLoadMatrix()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml) to load a matrix of type `glm::mat4` to the current matrix.

Anyway, an operation like [`glTranslatef()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) creates a new matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the new matrix. That's why consecutive calls to `glTranslatef` cause progressive "movement".

[`glPushMatrix / glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) store and restore the matrix on the matrix stack. So the consecutive movement can't work, because the current matrix stays the same at the begin of each frame.

---

One solution would be to store the translation to a variable and increment the variable:

```cpp
GLfloat trans_a = 0.0f;
GLflaot trans_b = 0.0f;

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.356, 0.701, 0.0, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

      trans_a += 0.5f;
      glTranslatef(trans_a, 0, 0);

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.8);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.8);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.5);
      glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();

      trans_b += 0.5f;
      glTranslatef(trans_b, 0, 0);

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(.0, .0, .0);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.2);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.2);
      glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

---

A more generalized solution is to get and store the current matrix (after the translation) by [`glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGet.xml) and to reload it by [`glLoadMatrix()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml):

```cpp
// init identity matrices
GLfloat mat_a[16] = {1, 0, 0, 0,    0, 1, 0, 0,    0, 0, 1, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1 };
GLfloat mat_b[16] = {1, 0, 0, 0,    0, 1, 0, 0,    0, 0, 1, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1 };

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.356, 0.701, 0.0, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

      glLoadMatrixf(mat_a)
      glTranslatef(0.5f, 0, 0);
      glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mat_a);

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.8);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.8);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.5);
      glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();

      glLoadMatrixf(mat_b)
      glTranslatef(0.5f, 0, 0);
      glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mat_b);

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(.0, .0, .0);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.2);
        glVertex2f(-0.8, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.2);
      glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Note, in this case `mat_a` and `mat_b` should be loaded after the initialization of the view matrix and when the view matrix changes, then the matrices would not consider that.

Comment: Woow, thanks man . i was so appreciate it for your helping me to solve this problem and telling me a lot of knowledge regarding opengl .